# Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions, cyclotomic-fields

I just started to study Galois theory and so I'm not too good with calculating Galois groups, I know that $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q})=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ but what about the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$? In particular I'm interested in the case $p=13$.

I can't find a solution online, maybe it's the same? Anyway what is it and how do you find it?

EDIT: Thinking about it given that $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{13})}/\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ it may be that the group I'm looking for is $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, am I right? And does this mean that the morphism are just $\zeta\to \zeta^k$ for $k\in \{1,\dots, 6\}$ (all in $\pmod{13}$ )?

Comment: Regarding your edit, $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{13})/\mathbb{Q})$ is $(\mathbb{Z}/13 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/12 \mathbb{Z}$. With this typo fixed, I suspect you can finish the rest.

Comment: So it's actually $\mathbb{Z}/(12/2)\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}?$

Comment: Yup! But your last edit seems confused again. In $\mathbb{Z}/12 \mathbb{Z}$, what is the $6$-element subgroup? (It is not $\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$.) And then what does that turn into in $(\mathbb{Z}/13 \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$?

Comment: Yes, I am.
It all comes down to me trying to understand how to do exercises without the will to carefully read the course notes but only the bit and pieces I thing will be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of Galois theory gives an order-reversing bijection between the subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\Bbb{Q})$ and the subfields of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. In particular the subfield $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ of degree $2$ corresponds to a subgroup $H\subset(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ of index $2$, and then
$$\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}))=H.$$
Of course $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic of even order, so it has precisely one subgroup of index $2$.

---

More explicitly, the canonical isomorphism $\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\Bbb{Q})\cong(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ is given by
$$(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\Bbb{Q}):\ k\ \longmapsto\ (\zeta_p\ \mapsto\ \zeta_p^k).$$
The unique subgroup of index $2$ in the multiplicative abelian group $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ is the subgroup of all squares, i.e. (nonzero) quadratic residues mod $p$. This shows that
$$\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}))=\left\{(\zeta_p\ \mapsto\ \zeta_p^{k^2}):\ k\in(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}\right\}.$$
For small values of $p$, such as $p=13$, you can simply list all six nonzero quadratic residues, and compute the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_p$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ as the product
$$f=\prod_{\sigma\in H}(X-\sigma(\zeta_p)),$$
where $H:=\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}))$.

Comment: I'm not sure If I get it, what is H in my case? In particular I'm looking for the elements to use to look for a minimal polynomial

Comment: @AlainNgalani I've made things a bit more explicit. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Ok, very clear.
Thanks.
So I guess this may be used to compute any such problem (so if we know how two fields f, G extend a third one  H and want to compute Gal (F/G))

Comment: Is there an error?
I tried listing the number of the form 2k and there are more then 6 (actually every element of $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$ is one) and morover they don't work.

Also you talk about wuadratic residues and then list the automoprhisms as $\zeta\to \zeta^{2k}$, shoudn't they be $\zeta\to \zeta^{k^2}$?

Comment: @AlainNgalani You are absolutely right! I have corrected this now.